# Dropdown login form without extensions

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

First of all, I'm starting with Joomla 3. I have a main menu with a login item and I want to dropdown the login form when this item is clicked, something like login on dropbox site.

I try hot login extension but not working well for me.

UPDATE

I create a new postion in my XML file called 'login'

```
<positions>
  <position>login</position>
```

And add this to the index.php

```
<div class="span7">
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="none" />
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="login" style="none" />
</div>
```

Finally, in the panel, I set to the Login Form module the login postion.

Now, my DOM is look like this:

```
<div class="span7">
   <ul class="nav menu">Menu itens...</ul>
   <form id="login-form">...</form>
</div>
```

How can I set the login form to open when the user click in one of the menu items?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the template, there are different methods. For example with Yootheme templates, you need to open the Login module in the Module Manager and set the position to "**menu**". With Rockettheme, you can set a module or a module position to a specific menu item via the Menu Manager.

Have a look at he demo site for the template you download and read any documentation as it will help.

Comment: Lodder, I'm creating a new template.

Comment: ah ok then. make sure you create a position called "menu", define it in your XML file and add it to your index.php in the template folder ;)